# Keeping track of two variables in C# Controller and View

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have two variables in my controller class, the first one is called currentUserId and it meant to store the current user that is logged into the website. The second variable, is currentRoomId and is meant to keep track of the current chat room the user is in. The issue is that when the user logs in it stores the correct variables into the two variables fine but then after it leaves the scope it does not save the values. The basic thing that I need to do is keep track of both of the variables. I am not sure what the best way to do this.

Here is what I currently have:

My Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities;
using SignalRChat.Models;
using System.Web;

namespace SignalRChat.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        ChatDBEntities DB = new ChatDBEntities();
        ChatDBEntities1 DB_Uno = new ChatDBEntities1();
        ChatDBEntities2 DB_Dos = new ChatDBEntities2();
        int currentUserId = -1;
        int currentRoomId = 1;

        public ActionResult Chat()
        {

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Users()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public bool AddMessage(string messageCont)
        {
            var authorId = (int) Session["currentUserId"];
            var message = new ChatMessage();
            message.Author = DB_Dos.ChatRoomUsers.Find(authorId).UserName; // Add Code to get the actual user
            message.AuthorId = authorId; ; //Add Code to get current user Id
            message.Message = messageCont;
            message.MessageDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            message.RoomId = (int)Session["currentRoomId"]; ; //Add Room Code
            message.RoomName = DB_Uno.ChatRooms.Find(currentRoomId).RoomName; // Get actual name based on id

            try
            {
                DB.ChatMessages.Add(message);
                DB.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public string GetMessages(int roomId)
        {
            Session["currentRoomId"] = roomId; 
            var messages = (from message in DB.ChatMessages where message.RoomId == roomId orderby message.MessageDate ascending select message).ToList();
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string json = serializer.Serialize(messages);
            return json;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public int GetCurrentRoomId()
        {
            return currentRoomId;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public int GetCurrentUserId()
        {
            return currentUserId;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public bool AddRoom(string chatRoom)
        {
            var room = new ChatRoom();

            room.IsActiveRoom = true;
            room.RoomName = chatRoom;
            room.isDefaultRoom = false;
            room.UserCount = 1;
            room.Id = -1;
            try
            {
                DB_Uno.ChatRooms.Add(room);       
                DB_Uno.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
               return false;
            }  
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public string GetRooms()
        {
            var rooms = DB_Uno.ChatRooms;
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string json = serializer.Serialize(rooms);
            return json;
        }

        public ActionResult AddUser()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddUser(ChatRoomUser user)
        {
            var users = DB_Dos.ChatRoomUsers;

            try
            {
                user.LastActivity = DateTime.UtcNow;
                user.RoomId = 1;
                user.RoomName = "General Chat";
                users.Add(user);
                DB_Dos.SaveChanges();
                currentUserId = user.UserId;
                return View("Chat");
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(ChatRoomUser LUser)
        {
            var userId = (from u in DB_Dos.ChatRoomUsers where u.UserName == LUser.UserName select u.UserId).ToList();
            var user = DB_Dos.ChatRoomUsers.Find(userId[0]);
            if(user.password == LUser.password)
            {
                currentUserId = user.UserId;
                user.LastActivity = DateTime.UtcNow;
                Session["currentRoomId"] = user.RoomId;
                Session["currendUserId"] = user.UserId;
                DB_Dos.SaveChanges();
                return View("Chat");
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Chat";
}
<h2>General Chat</h2>

<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="upper-wrapper">
        <div id="available-rooms-dialog">
            <h4>Available Rooms</h4>
        </div>
        <form id="ava-rooms">
            <input type="button" onclick="GetRoomName()" id=" createroom" value="Create Room" />
        </form>
        <div id="discussion-dialog">
            <textarea rows="30" cols="50" id="discussion"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="message-dialog">
        <textarea rows="3" id="message">Type your message</textarea>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Post" />
        <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="enter-sends-message"/>
        Enter sends message
    </div>
</div>
@section scripts
    {
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var json;
    var currentUserId;
    var CurrentRoomId;
    var MyVariable = '@ViewBag.MyVariable';


    $(function () {
        LoadRooms();
        // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
        chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
            // Add the message to the page.
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "Get",
                url: "@Url.Action("GetCurrentRoomId", "Home")",
                success: function (data)
                {
                    currentRoomId = data;
                }
            });

            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "Get",
                url: "@Url.Action("GetCurrentUserId", "Home")",
                success: function (data)
                {
                    currentUserId = data;
                }
            });

            //TODO: Add Record to Server
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "Post",
                url: "@Url.Action("AddMessage", "Home")",
                data: { messageCont: message.toString()},
                success: function (data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        //access with data[i].modelattribute
                    }
                }
            });

            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "Get",
                url: "@Url.Action("GetMessages", "Home")",
                success: function (data) {
                    json = data;
                    var obj = JSON.parse(json);
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        //access with data[i].modelattribute
                        $('#discussion').append(htmlEncode(obj[i].Author) + " : " + htmlEncode(obj[i].Message) + "\r\n");
                    }
                }
            });

        };

        // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
        // Set initial focus to message input box.
        $('#message').focus();
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                // Call the Send method on the hub.
                chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });
        });
    });

    // This optional function html-encodes messages for display in the page.
    function htmlEncode(value) {
        var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
        return encodedValue;

    }
    function GetRoomName() {
        var newRoomName = prompt('Enter a new Room Name', 'Name');
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "Post",
            url: "@Url.Action("AddRoom", "Home")",
            data: { chatRoom: newRoomName },
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    //access with data[i].modelattribute
                }
            }
        });
    }

        function LoadRooms() {

           $.ajax(
           {
               type: "Get",
               url: "@Url.Action("GetRooms", "Home")",
                success: function (data) {
                    json = data;
                    var obj = JSON.parse(json);
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        //access with data[i].modelattribute
                        // Add an Onlick event to this statment that calls LoadRoomMessages
                        //onclick="GetRoomName()"
                        $('#ava-rooms').append("<input type=\"button\" " +"onclick=LoadRoomMessages(" + obj[i].Id + ") " + "id=\"" + obj[i].RoomName +"\"" + "value=\"" + obj[i].RoomName +"\" />");
                    }
                }
        });

        }

        function LoadRoomMessages(id)
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "Get",
                url: "@Url.Action("GetMessages", "Home")",
                data: { roomId: id },
                success: function (data)
                {
                      $('#discussion').empty();
                      json = data;
                      var obj = JSON.parse(json);
                      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                      {
                          $('#discussion').append(htmlEncode(obj[i].Author) + " : " + htmlEncode(obj[i].Message) + "\r\n");
                      }
                }
            });
        }

</script>
}
}
```

Is there any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) to store these variables. They will available on any controller or view as long as the session didn't expire.

To set session variables on controller

```
Session["currentRoomId"]  = roomId;
```

To get session variables on controllers

```
int roomId = (int)Session["currentRoomId"];
```

To get session variables on a razor view

```
@Session["currentRoomId"]
```

Comment: That sounds exactly what I need. How would I implement this?

Comment: Okay, great. Thank you! I will start with that

Comment: Do you happen to know the references for Session? Because when I use that Reference above, it does not have Session Keyword.

Comment: @user977154: is your controller a mvc controller or web api controller? It should work on the controller of your example. You could try with `HttpContext.Current.Session`

Comment: It recognizes HttpContext but it does not that statement does not work. I have tried building it just to make sure my intellisense is not working.

Comment: Which method are you trying to assign it in?  You can't do it outside an action because you don't have a Session in scope there.

Comment: @user977154: please add your code to assign the session variables on the question.

Comment: Okay, I got it appear in my Login Method at the bottom. But I need the variable to store the value after the Login method because a lot of the other methods require those values.

Comment: I added my code. I really appreciate this help by the way.

Comment: @Claudio Redi: I have just tried using TempData and I am getting the same result. After I login() i try to add a message but I am getting a  null exception saying that Session["currentUserId"] is null (AddMessage())

Comment: @user977154: I see that you marked the question as resolved. Do you still need assistance?